# Is there any parameter in any SDK for enabling access logging in GCP Vertex AI?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

[enabling access logging on the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV1Vb.png)seeking for some support in terms of enabling logging via the SDK(Vertex AI or AI platform or any other).Just as we enable it on the UI(pls refer attached file) & other times via gcloud command like this->
gcloud ai endpoints deploy-model ENDPOINT_ID--region=LOCATION --model=MODEL_ID --display-name=DEPLOYED_MODEL_NAME --machine-type=MACHINE_TYPE --accelerator=count=2,type=nvidia-tesla-t4 --disable-container-logging --enable-access-logging

Does AI platform or vertex ai or any other SDK comprise of any API/parameter which would allow us to enable access logging? If yes, could you please point in that direction?

Answer (score 0):

The Vertex API defines a `DeployedModel`, which is the object deployed to an `Endpoint`.

`DeployedModel` has an attribute `enableAccessLogging`, which I think may be what you're looking for.

REST API: [`enableAccessLogging`](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.endpoints#deployedmodel)

gcloud: [`--enable-access-logging`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/endpoints/deploy-model#--enable-access-logging)

Python SDK: [`enable_access_logging`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.types.DeployedModel)